# Docker compose throws permission denied on mac

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using this on Mac. Creating and running the docker image works fine.  But with docker-compose I get the following error:

`"exec: \"./boot.sh\": permission denied": unknown`

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

RUN adduser -D teamreacher
WORKDIR /home/teamreacher

# copy and install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m venv venv
RUN venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
RUN venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy the app
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x boot.sh # Giving execution permissions here...

RUN chown -R teamreacher:teamreacher ./
USER teamreacher

# expose port and run server
EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["./boot.sh"] # ...so why do I get permission denied here?
```

**Docker compose file:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  teamreacher-server:
    build: ./server
    volumes:
      - ./server:/home/teamreacher
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

I've looked through similiar questions but none provided an answer for my specific problem.

**boot.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

source venv/bin/activate
exec gunicorn -b :5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - wsgi:app
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By bind-mounting your `./server` directory into the same location where `boot.sh` is located on the container, you're rewriting the permissions so that it is no longer executable.

Please see the below demonstration:

```
TJs-MacBook-Pro:stackoverflow tj$ ls -lah
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   4 tj    wheel   128B Dec 23 14:58 .
drwxrwxrwt  15 root  wheel   480B Dec 23 15:05 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 tj    wheel   143B Dec 23 14:57 docker-compose.yaml
drwxr-xr-x   6 tj    wheel   192B Dec 23 15:03 server
TJs-MacBook-Pro:stackoverflow tj$ ls -lah server/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  6 tj  wheel   192B Dec 23 15:03 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 tj  wheel   128B Dec 23 14:58 ..
-rw-------  1 tj  wheel   177B Dec 23 15:06 .ash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 tj  wheel   508B Dec 23 14:56 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--  1 tj  wheel   105B Dec 23 14:56 boot.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 tj  wheel     0B Dec 23 14:56 requirements.txt
TJs-MacBook-Pro:stackoverflow tj$ docker-compose build
Building teamreacher-server
Step 1/13 : FROM python:3.7-alpine
 ---> 020295c920c6
Step 2/13 : RUN adduser -D teamreacher
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7dbd3131c941
Step 3/13 : WORKDIR /home/teamreacher
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d2754b1b8dc2
Step 4/13 : COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2d468491a297
Step 5/13 : RUN python -m venv venv
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0c135fa6f980
Step 6/13 : RUN venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ea7df7153a5a
Step 7/13 : RUN venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> db540a631c19
Step 8/13 : COPY . .
 ---> 174a91493622
Step 9/13 : RUN chmod +x boot.sh # Giving execution permissions here...
 ---> Running in b9cedb0f163a
Removing intermediate container b9cedb0f163a
 ---> 6d5ce7df1969
Step 10/13 : RUN chown -R teamreacher:teamreacher ./
 ---> Running in 2e672e8ac6ef
Removing intermediate container 2e672e8ac6ef
 ---> 48342c4c31e3
Step 11/13 : USER teamreacher
 ---> Running in 4d3bc99fb515
Removing intermediate container 4d3bc99fb515
 ---> 11bdc7be7f84
Step 12/13 : EXPOSE 5000
 ---> Running in 0924db9c175b
Removing intermediate container 0924db9c175b
 ---> 0d96d773f42f
Step 13/13 : CMD ["./boot.sh"] # ...so why do I get permission denied here?
 ---> Running in 4a33ab4e342a
Removing intermediate container 4a33ab4e342a
 ---> a9acefb4eeac
Successfully built a9acefb4eeac
Successfully tagged stackoverflow_teamreacher-server:latest
TJs-MacBook-Pro:stackoverflow tj$ docker run stackoverflow_teamreacher-server ls -lah /home/teamreacher
total 24
drwxr-sr-x    1 teamreac teamreac    4.0K Dec 23 20:07 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Dec 23 19:56 ..
-rw-------    1 teamreac teamreac     177 Dec 23 20:06 .ash_history
-rw-r--r--    1 teamreac teamreac     508 Dec 23 19:56 Dockerfile
-rwxr-xr-x    1 teamreac teamreac     105 Dec 23 19:56 boot.sh
-rw-r--r--    1 teamreac teamreac       0 Dec 23 19:56 requirements.txt
drwxr-sr-x    1 teamreac teamreac    4.0K Dec 23 19:59 venv
TJs-MacBook-Pro:stackoverflow tj$ docker run -v $(pwd)/server:/home/teamreacher stackoverflow_teamreacher-server ls -lah /home/teamreacher
total 16
drwxr-xr-x    6 teamreac teamreac     192 Dec 23 20:03 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Dec 23 19:56 ..
-rw-------    1 teamreac teamreac     177 Dec 23 20:06 .ash_history
-rw-r--r--    1 teamreac teamreac     508 Dec 23 19:56 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--    1 teamreac teamreac     105 Dec 23 19:56 boot.sh
-rw-r--r--    1 teamreac teamreac       0 Dec 23 19:56 requirements.txt
```

Comment: A bit late to the game but yep, your answer is more thoroughly explained, marked as answered.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I had to give the file boot.sh execution permissions on my mac as well. That means running:

```
chmod +x boot.sh
```

in my project directory.

Comment: That would also work - Please see my above answer for the explanation of the root cause. You beat me by a minute ;-)